# Using Camel netty4 "unsupported message type" exception when sending String over UDP

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

Here is part of my camel route

```
<bean class="io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder" id="stringEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camelContext">

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:startMessageSend"/>
        <to uri="netty4:udp://localhost:5000?encoder=#stringEncoder&amp;sync=false"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

When I send a simple string over to this endpoint.

```
            String udpMsgBody = "hello world!";
            template.sendBody(udpMsgBody);
```

I get following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported message type: DefaultAddressedEnvelope (expected: DatagramPacket, AddressedEnvelope<ByteBuf, SocketAddress>, ByteBuf)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.filterOutboundMessage(NioDatagramChannel.java:324)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:697)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1114)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:705)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:763)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:698)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder.write(MessageToMessageEncoder.java:102)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:705)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:980)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1032)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:965)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

However when I send the Exchange body as byteBuf I get no exception and message is sent over UDP fine.

```
            ByteBuf bbuffer = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(udpMsgBody.getBytes());
            template.sendBody(udpMsgBody);
```

My question is that even though I am using a proper StringEncoder, why can I not send a string over netty4?

Note I am using camel 2.15.2

Comment: Seems like if I send over tcp instead of udp, the stringEncoder's encode() method gets hit (debugged and put a break point on encode() method). Does camel support udp encoder ? Camel Version 2.15.2 & netty4

Comment: Update: io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder encode() method does not get hit, only if I use camel-netty4's default encoders, they seem to get hit. org.apache.camel.component.netty4.codec.DatagramPacketStringDecoder. Seems like on camel route if for netty4 udp endpoint only camel's packaged encoders can be used and not the ones from netty itself.